# How to skip or truncate character or symbols from text I need. Web-scraping with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get price (61,990) between `div` tag but how can I get rid of currency symbol?

[image]

Same as here, I need to grab rating only (4.7), but I don't need anything after that, such that `img src`. How can I ignore it? Or skip it?

[image]

**Code sample:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

price = []
ratings=[]
response = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniq")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'}): 
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
    rating=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. You just need to use the `.text` method and treat it like a normal string. In this case, retain all but the first character.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

price = []
ratings=[]
response = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniq")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'}):
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'}).text[1:]
    rating=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34'}).text
print(price)
print(rating)
```

```
Out[110]: '4.3'
Out[111]: '52,990'
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!